# Get corresponding value from other sheet in excel (only returning first column)

Tags: arrays, excel, search

I currently have the following formula, where the intention is to search one sheet for names, then pull the job title from another sheet with the same layout.  However, it keeps only returning job titles from C column, and I to some extent know why, but I have no idea how to get the index, and in turn cell address call, to return matches with the correct column value.

Essentially the ActualVolunteerSchedule sheet has names, the TaskingSchedule has jobs in the time slots.
In EmailPrep sheet I am combining the time marker from column A with the job title from inside the table based on finding a matching name from row 1 in the email prep sheet.

So given a range say B:H on sheet1 - find all cells containing NAME, then grab cell contents from sheet2 with the same address.  NAME found at sheet1!$C$3 then return value of sheet2!$C$3
INDIRECT("TaskingSchedule"&"!"&RIGHT(CELL("address",INDEX(ActualVolunteerSchedule!$C$1:$H$74,
SMALL(IF(ActualVolunteerSchedule!$C$1:$H$74=B$1,ROW(ActualVolunteerSchedule!$C$1:$H$74)),ROWS(A$3:A3)))),4))

Actual File
[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_q4mpAyixBE5JGplkwwfyFOGGssAGzS3vXc0rnpg75s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you upload a sample of the data?

Comment: Linked fo google sheet I'm working on

Comment: Given the complexity of the workbook, could you briefly walk us through an example? e.g. _cell A1's formula returns a value of Y, but I expect it to return the value X from Sheet3's cell B2, etc._

Comment: Please expand your question like Phylyp told. In what cell does this formula you describe go? From what worksheets should what be pulled, and what does it pull right now?

Comment: @Luuklag added requested information